# What should "git reflog show <ref>" show?

Tags: git, show, ref, reflog

I have two branches, master and b1. When I'm on b1, 'git reflog show' displays all the changes to b1. However, after I switch to master and run 'git reflog show b1', it displays something different. The manpage for 'git reflog' does not explain how the arg, <ref>, affects the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows the history of `<ref>`. If `<ref>` is not provided, it shows the history of HEAD. Note that this is **not** what HEAD *points to*, but rather HEAD itself. So when you do a `git reflog show` while on b1, it is showing the history of HEAD, not b1. When you do `git reflog show b1`, it shows the history of b1. So that is where the difference comes from.

Comment: Ah hah, that's what I missed. By default, 'git reflog show' displays changes to HEAD, and not the "branch" itself. Thank you.